# Swift Func called after expected

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, function

I have a button setup so that it saves a CK record based on a users choice from a different part of the UI. Once the function is called the CKRecord is saved in a variable. The next operation the code should take is unwrapping that variable and using it to edit and save the CK record. The Issue is the function I call first, loadChallengeRecord(), isn't the first operation made when the button is pressed. Instead the unwrapping function is run first which is causing the program to exit the unwrap function because the record is nil, and then the loadChallengeRecord() function is called late. Here is the example:

```
func loadChallengeRecord() {
    if let unwrapped = existingChallengeToDetails {
        recordID = CKRecord.ID(recordName: unwrapped, zoneID: zone)
        publicDatabase.fetch(withRecordID: recordID!) { (record, error) in
            if record != nil {
                self.currentChallenge = record
            } else {
                print("error fetching challenge record from server")
            }
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func btnVote(_ sender: Any) {
// load record and save it to var existingChallengeToDetails

loadChallengeRecord()

if let unwrapped = existingChallengeToDetails { }// edit and save record 
else { // error }
```

What am i doing wrong? How can i fix this? Can I denote a priority for these functions to run?

Comment: please post `loadChallengeRecord`

Comment: i think its async function ... that is why you are facing this problem

Comment: Hi @jawadAli - I added the function above the button handler. Thank you!

Comment: yes its async function ... so you need to wait ...

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other two answers worked for the specific case, and work for many causes, but they weren't exactly what I was looking for. I kept running to similar issues and after some research I finally found what I was looking for: [Semaphores](http://aolvera.com/wp/2019/09/01/using-dispatchsemaphore-to-make-synchronous-calls-in-swift/)

Here is a basic explanation:

```
func doSomething() {
  let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0) // Setup the semaphore to value:0
  var x = 1
  var y = 2 
  if y != 0 {
    var sum = x + y
    semaphore.signal(). // Sends signal that code is complete
    // the code can continue from where semaphore.wait() is located. 
  } 

  semaphore.wait()  // Wait for semaphore.signal() to fire, then continue to return

  return sum // only after semaphore.signal() fires will this code run
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your function with completion handler like this

```
func loadChallengeRecord(completion:@escaping ()->Void) {
    if let unwrapped = existingChallengeToDetails {
        recordID = CKRecord.ID(recordName: unwrapped, zoneID: zone)
        publicDatabase.fetch(withRecordID: recordID!) { (record, error) in
            defer { completion }
            if record != nil {
                self.currentChallenge = record
            } else {
                print("error fetching challenge record from server")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this ... when it returns completion you can do other stuff dependent on this

```
loadChallengeRecord {
            
            // do your stuff here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to do the things you have to do in the (asynchronous) completion handler

```
func loadChallengeRecord() {
    guard let unwrapped = existingChallengeToDetails else { return }
    recordID = CKRecord.ID(recordName: unwrapped, zoneID: zone)
    publicDatabase.fetch(withRecordID: recordID!) { (record, error) in
        if let record = record {
            self.currentChallenge = record
            // edit and save record 
        } else {
            print("error fetching challenge record from server", error!)
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func btnVote(_ sender: Any) {
    // load record and save it to var existingChallengeToDetails
    loadChallengeRecord()
}
```